# Where is the appropriate place to post a question about the topic of "automated reasoning?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-crossover

Where is the appropriate place to post a question about the topic of "automated reasoning?"

---

I am having some difficulty navigating Stack Exchange as a generalist.

This is a multi-disciplinary field encompassing a wide a variety of fields, such as cognitive science, data science, psychology, philosophy, artificial intelligence; etc.

---

This topic reaches as far as obscure topics such as Avestan, to give some understanding of the breadth of this topic.

(https://bstrategyhub.com/sanskrit-is-the-best-language-for-artificial-intelligence-says-nasa/)

---

This is an example of one such question where it is confusing as to which website to post in:--

[What is Hofstadter's ontology for symbols?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/what-is-hofstadters-ontology-for-symbols)

---

If such a question of this manner were posted in **Philosophy site of Stack Exchange**, how would this question differ if it were posted in another website of Stack Exchange, such as the **Statistics website of Stack Exchange** or the **Artificial Intelligence website of Stack Exchange**?

---

**Prior Research**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_reasoning)
- (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-automated/)
- Bredeweg, Bert, and Peter Struss. "Current topics in qualitative reasoning." *AI Magazine* 24.4 (2003): 13-13.
- (https://psychologydictionary.org/automated-reasoning/)
- (https://cs.anu.edu.au/research/student-research-projects/automated-reasoning-artificial-intelligence)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalist)
- (https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~horst/cogrobo/papers/CADS.pdf)
- (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030172961)

Comment: To be pedantic, none of the sites are appropriate to discuss things. But if you have a specific question, a couple of sites might fit: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=automated+reasoning but which one is the best fit greatly matter per question or intended answers.

Comment: Fair enough. Let me know how this question can be improved. My natural inclination is the philosophy site, but that could simply be because I am most familiar with that website.

Comment: It needs some users from the other possible sites to chime in, assuming it is even possible to come up with definitive redirection guidance. Did you consider the per-site chatrooms to get some feedback on this topic?

Comment: Regarding the overlapping topic, each site will have its experts, and will answer from their knowledge as best as they can: [Philosophy.SE] will answer from philosophy side, [Stats.SE] will answer from statistics side, [AI.SE] will answer from AI side, (we also have [CogSci.SE]), etc. If the question is generic enough, then just choose 1 site that you think will be the most applicable.

Comment: I've already briefly mentioned this topic in the philosophy chatroom-analogue, the Symposium, to the Philosophy Stack Exchange website.

Comment: Can you maybe add a description of what you would like to ask?

Comment: Automated theorem provers might be on topic on one of the Mathematics sites but I am not one of their users. This does not seem closely related to statistics though so neither CrossValidated nor DataScience looks a good fit.

Comment: I think it depends on not only the question itself, but also what sort of answer you'd be looking for; what area of expertise are you wanting to focus on?  For example, a math driven formula?  Or a philosophical answer?

Comment: Automated reasoning in data science: < https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~horst/cogrobo/papers/CADS.pdf >.

Comment: I think some forms of systems thinking uses statistical methods -- so that's an example of how you could post a question in statistics websites.

Comment: [ @fbueckert ]

That makes sense. May I politely suggest that we could expand this line of thinking and develop a full answer from this?

Comment: The best I could do is answer in the general sense; I'm not at *all* conversant with automated reasoning to give a specific answer, so for the most part, it won't really help you.  There may be nuances I'm missing.

Comment: That's fine. I appreciate the work.

Comment: [ @mdewey ] I've included this < https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/what-is-hofstadters-ontology-for-symbols >, as an example. You provided good input. :)

Comment: Alright lads. I've have touched on this in the philosophy and A.I. chat-rooms about this topic. (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52558569#52558569)